# No such file or directory in python (Uninstall/Install Anaconda)

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I was using Anaconda3 with python 3.0, but a code in internet didn't work.
So i tried to uninstall Anaconda3 and install Anaconda2 with python 2.7.
The problem is that at the beginning I had a directory called anaconda3, after I eliminated it. Now i have a folder called anaconda2 but when i try to install TensorFlow with

```
 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

or uninstall (if there is an other version) with

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

It gives me:
-bash: /home/s_rausa/anaconda3/bin/pip: No such file or directory

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that your `PATH` still has `pip` registered in `/home/s_rausa/anaconda3/bin/pip`, even though you have now uninstalled that and installed anaconda2.

If you run `echo $PATH`, you should be able to confirm that.

I'm assuming that anaconda3 automatically added a line such as

```
PATH="/home/s_rausa/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

automatically to your `.bashrc` in your home directory (or whatever config/profile file you use).

You can now fix this issue by simply having that point to your new `anaconda` installation, by replacing `anaconda3` with `anaconda2` in that line in your `.bashrc` that sets the `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i didn't refresh the session of Putty.